# WPF: disable inheritance of properties

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I would like to use a TabControl as the main navigation in the application I am working on. So I would like to make the font in the headers of the TabItems bigger and also give it another background-color. However, I do **not** want this to be inherited. For example,
if I use this code:

```
<TabControl FontSize="18pt">
  <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
    <Button>Button 1</Button>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The font in the button is also 18pt big. I know that this is normal dependency property behaviour because the property is inherited, but that's not what I want in this case. I would like to change the TabItems without changing anything in the children. Isn't that possible? Because re-setting all children to default values is a PITA.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the `Header` as an explicit control (`TextBlock` or `Label` for instance), on which you apply a style :

```
<TabControl FontSize="18pt">
  <TabItem>
    <TabItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource tabHeaderStyle}">Tab 1</TextBlock>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Button>Button 1</Button>
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I need. I had expected this to be a bit easier but this is nonetheless what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to rethink this a bit.  You can't just say "Don't inherit," because the control has to inherit its property values from somewhere.

This works:

```
  <TabControl x:Name="Test" FontSize="36">
    <TabControl.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ElementName=Test, Path=FontSize}"/>
      </Style>        
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Test" FontSize="24">
      <Button>Another test</Button>
    </TabItem>
  </TabControl>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rethink"? I think my claims are pretty decent, or not? Why can't such a basic task not be made easy by WPF? XAML is cool and all but sometimes I have the feeling Microsoft sacrifices ease of use a bit too much.

Comment: What I meant by "rethink": your question seems to have as its premise that the button has a default font size, and that what you want to do is stop it from inheriting.  But what you almost certainly actually want the is for the button to continue inheriting its properties, but from something other than its immediate parent - that way, if you change the font size on the Window (say), the button's size will change too.  Thomas's answer achieves this by (essentially) pulling the tab item out of the inheritance tree.  My answer does it by giving the button something different to inherit from.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, you helped me quite a bit in understanding WPF. I think I worded my question bad. I just wanted the main manu (tabcontrol) to have a completely different look from the controls inside. Then inheritance came in the way. So I tried to find answers regarding "disabling" inheritance which is the wrong way obviously. Thanks again.

Comment: I have found aspects of WPF fantastically difficult to learn precisely because it's impossible to make progress when your mental model of what it's doing is wrong.  Most technologies I've learned are more forgiving; if you don't understand something, you can at least get *a* result and see how your ideas fall short.  With WPF, stuff either works flawlessly or it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Example of templated Headers for each states:
The fonts properties of the header content are not propaged into the TabControl content.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource TabItemGeneralTemplate.Normal}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource TabItemGeneralTemplate.Selected}"/>               
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource TabItemGeneralTemplate.Hover}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        ...

        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemGeneralTemplate.Selected">
           <Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="#FF343434" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemGeneralTemplate.Hover">
           <Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="{DynamicResource Background.Primary}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemGeneralTemplate.Normal">
           <Label Content="{Binding}" Foreground="#FF7C7C7C"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```